# Remove last TD before append the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code:

```
html += '<tr>';
html += '<td>AAA</td>';
html += '<td>BBB</td>';
html += '<td>CCC</td>';
html += '<td>DDD</td>';
html += '<td>EEE</td>';
html += '<td>FFF</td>';
html += '</tr>';

$(html).appendTo("#fabricanteBody");
$(html).appendTo("#selFabricanteBody");
```

How do I remove the last `td` (`html += '<td>FFF</td>'`) element on the `html` var before append it to `#selFabricanteBody`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('tr > td:last-child').remove();
```

or

```
$('tr > td').last().remove();
```

see demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vc3rf1wu/2/)  and [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vc3rf1wu/3/).

Comment: Ummm I want to remove from `html` did your code does that?

Comment: Fine, your solution do what I ask by I complete forgot to mention this part: for `#fabricanteBody` last TD should exists, and should be removed for `#selFabricanteBody`, for that reason I ask for delete it on `html` var directly, can you take a look to this new requirement?

Comment: @ReynierPM you find answer or still want any help .. I'm here if you still want anything

Comment: No, I didn't find a way to do it yet, if you could help me with the latest comment I leave will be fine, just that I need to add in your code. Your solution is fine and do what I ask in first but I complete forgot to mention the things I did in comment before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67879/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-mohamed-yousef).